# What is the priority of event handling and timer servicing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timer, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to understand the execution priority of Javascript. I have a code where a timer runs to callback a function after 15 seconds. However, an event might occur just before that and the even handler function may be called.

1. What happens if the timer goes off when the event is being serviced?
2. Does JS interrupt the event and service the timer and come back to the event? [From ejohn's blog on How JavaScript Timer Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/), this is probably not what happens.
3. What happens if the timer goes off when the even is being serviced and the event handler executes `clearTimeout(theTimerThatJustWentOff)`? Will the timer service routine run after we exit the event handler?
4. How much will these behaviours vary across browsers?

I am not asking what happens in a race condition of two asynchronous events. In my case, one has occurred and is being serviced while the second occurs.

Comment: Events queue up and are dispatched. Because it's all asynchronous, your code can't really tell (or predict) how things will happen. There's no preemption.

Comment: If a function triggers an event synchronously (e.g. `node.dispatchEvent(new Event())`), that event will block the function until it resolves (or does something asynchronous). If you have two asynchronous things, it's anybodies guess.

Comment: @Pointy - realize that events will be asynchronous. But I have been reading that JS is single threaded (I assume it still is) and only one thing executes at a time (By this I assume there is no assembly style interrupt->push_to_stack->service_interrupt->pop_from_stack). So there should be a pending timer service if I am running code when the timer goes off - I am right?

Comment: Think of the timer mechanism as triggering timer events.  Those events queue up just like mouse or keyboard events.

Comment: @PaulS. - I am not asking what happens in a race condition of two asynchronous events. In my case, one has occurred and is being serviced while the second occurs.

Comment: @Pointy - So, can I remove the timer service from the queue by executing `clearTimeout(timer_that_went_off_and_is_in_queue_to_be_serviced)`?

Comment: @LordLoh. yes - if you clear a timeout before the event has been dispatched, the handler will not run.

Comment: [Test case for questions 3 and 4](http://jsfiddle.net/4hz6j/). The timer is cleared after it was due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript runs single-threaded. That should answer your questions. So

1. the timer doesnt go off while its running. When your function finishes or when it yields (by doing a continuation with setTimeout for example) your trigger will run again.
2. no.
3. no. - see 1.
4. Shouldn't vary.